# Projection of a continuous random vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-variables

I found an article which deals with continuous random vectors $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$ $(n>4)$ with this property for $m=1$ and $m=4$

> exists $K>0$ s.t. for any vector space $E\subset \mathbb R^n$ of dimension $m$ the density function of $Proj_E(X)$ viewed as function on $E$ is bounded by $K$

Does this proposition imply that the density function of $X$ on $\mathbb R^n$ is bounded (even by a different constant) or vice versa?

Comment: It would help if you could tell us which article you are talking about(or if you could give us a link to it)

Comment: the link is here, you can find the previous formulation at page 3, (C1) https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.09656v1